# getting Error CS0029 unable to convert anonymous type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to C# and entity Framework. Can someone guide me to the answer to this problem?
**unable to return query**

```
 public IQueryable<Routing_Tool_Init_SP> GetInit_SP(int id)
        {
            #region InitItemJoin
            var query = (from rt in _context.Set<Routing_Tool>()
                         join rp in _context.Set<Routing_Tool_Prioritization_Matrix>()
                             on rt.Id equals rp.RoutingToolId into grouping
                         from rp in grouping.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new { rt, rp }).FirstOrDefault();

            return query;
        }
```

Comment: Well, how would you expect to convert an anonymous type `new { rt, rp }` to a `Routing_Tool_Init_SP`?

Comment: I am following MS instructions online.

Comment: this works:  public Routing_Tool GetItemsInitById(int id)
        {
            return _context.Routing_Tool.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        }

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your method returns IQueryable of something. However since you are accessing the query with .FirstOrDefault() you are executing the query immediately and retrieving just a single entity of Routing_Tool (or default) and no queryable. Check your var for explicit type for more clearification.

Return the whole query without executing it. Let the caller execute the query when and how it is needed.

Comment: Thanks that send me on the right path. No a complete solution since I am ignorant on how to ask a better question on this subject. But the right path!

Answer (score 0):

The final solution to make the method work:

```
public Routing_Tool GetItemsInitById(int id)
        {
            var initPage = _context.Routing_Tool
                .Include(pub => pub.Routing_Tool_Prioritization_Matrices)
                .Where(rt => rt.Id == id)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            return initPage;
        }
```